# Is there a way to create a dynamic model that has dynamic rules to validate dynamic properties using Yii2?

Tags: php, model, yii2, rules, dynamic-properties

I have a bunch of dynamic forms which means I can't know beforehand what and how many input fields a form has and how many forms it will be. I would like to create a dynamic model that has dynamic rules for validating all kinds of input fields and for all forms which are unknown beforehand. I have read [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-dynamicmodel.html), but it's not enough to approach what I want and I am not sure if it is possible to create such a model.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Can you show us the part of the code you already have?

Answer (score 1):

View this solution:

https://www.google.pl/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=yii2+eav

I hope it helps